# delimiter ">" invalid: only minimum literal and parameter separators are allowed

Tags: html, validation

I'm running my work through the validator and I get this error for the first line.

delimiter ">" invalid: only minimum literal and parameter separators are allowed

The error is apparently on the > at the end of this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC>
```

I don't wanna post too much of my code, sorry.

Edit: I think I forgot to change the HTML thing to HTML 5 in the validator. Sorry, I herp and derp.

Answer (score 1):

Public isn't valid for HTML5, remove it and it should validate (that line at least! :)).

Answer (score 1):

Here you find the header definitions for html documents

http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

for HTML5 it is only

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```